# What does the word buck means in 'the buck stops here'?

Tags: idioms, idiom-meaning

I know that the meaning of the idiom 'the buck stops here' is to accept responsibility. For example, The buck stops here with me. I take the blame for the team's performance.

There are multiple meanings of the buck i.e. dollar, a male animal, antelope, and buckskin. I was wondering what does the buck means in this idiom.

Comment: This is explained in the [Wikipedia article on "buck-passing"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck_passing).

Comment: I don't read Wikipedia articles as the articles are not entirely accurate. Many universities don't allow Wikis due to factual inaccuracies in many articles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Individual words in an idiom don’t necessarily  mean anything as used in the idiom - that’s one of the things that makes it an idiom. In this case you can read buck as responsibility. Wikipedia mentions a knife with a handle made from an animal part (buckhorn) that was passed as a counter in a poker game as part of the entomology of the idiom “passing the buck”. The buck stops here comes from passing the buck.

Comment: I don’t see it - where is the error?

Comment: I think you mean the words don't mean anything 'outside of the context of the idiom' 'the Buck' in the context of this idiom means 'responsibility' or 'accountability'

Comment: Yes, what Jeff says. :)

Comment: The word buck has many meanings outside the idiom as the question lists. Individual words as used in the idiom do not necessarily have a meaning - the idiom as a whole has a meaning. But in thus case it goes mean responsibility.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I did not knew that words in idioms don't have exact meanings. There are many idioms with confusing words. They seem to be born out of ordinary rather than literary language.